# Show that the families of hyberbolae $x^2-y^2=a$, $xy=b$ create an orthogonal grid: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Show that the families of hyberbolae $x^2-y^2=a$, $xy=b$ create an
>   orthogonal grid.

My idea is to find the intersection points of the hyperbolae, and then take a look at the $y_1' \cdot y_2'$ at those points. It should be $-1$.

From
$\begin{cases}
|y|=\sqrt{x^2-a} \\
y=\frac{b}{x}
\end{cases}$
we get $\sqrt{x^2-a}=\pm \frac{b}{x}$.

My derivatives are $y_1'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}$, $y_2'= \frac{b}{x^2}$.

$y_1'\cdot y_2' = \pm \frac{x}{b} \cdot \frac{b}{x^2} = \pm \frac{1}{x} \neq -1$.

I will be grateful for a hint or a full solution, but what most concerns me is where did my reasoning go astray.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your $y'_1$ is incorrect.

Comment: Derivative of a composed function for $y_1$

Comment: @Rahul  Thanks, I see now! $y_1'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}$, and $y_1' \cdot y_2' = \pm 1$, but what do I do about $\pm$?

Comment: Implicit differentiation gives $2x-2y_1y_1'=0$, that is $y_1'=x/y_1$.  Now $y_2'=-b/x^2$.  Multiply both and use that in the intersection points we have $y_1=y_2$.

Comment: Check out this answer I made to a similar question! Hope I helped! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027827/show-that-these-curve-families-are-orthogonal-fxy-c-and-y2-x2-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curves are level lines of the functions
$$F(x,y):=x^2-y^2,\qquad G(x,y):=xy\ .$$
Given a point ${\bf z}_0=(x_0,y_0)\ne{\bf 0}$ the level line of $F$ through ${\bf z}_0$ is orthogonal to $\nabla F({\bf z}_0)=(2x_0,-2y_0)$, and the level line of $G$ through ${\bf z}_0$ is orthogonal to $\nabla G({\bf z}_0)=(y_0,x_0)$. As $\nabla F({\bf z}_0)\cdot\nabla F({\bf z}_0)=0$ these two gradients are orthogonal to each other, and so are the tangents to the two level lines.

Comment: Now this is cool!

Answer (score 0):

These are the real and imaginary parts of $z\mapsto z^2$. Then use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Which incidentally shows you how to generate many other examples.